# How do I make a item teleport back to me when I die or drop it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is what I have so far, I need the command to find this specific item and teleport it back to me. (I don't want to turn on keep inventory because I want all of the other items to drop.)

```
/give CrimsonCreates minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Dash Attack\"}"}}
```

```
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item,nbt={}] run tp @s CrimsonCreates
```

Comment: Your problem will be that the chunks unload. They might even potentially unload in the same tick that you die in, meaning that it's going to get really hard to check which location you were even in before you died. It might be possible with /forceload by constantly un-forcing the chunks around you and forcing the chunk you're in and then move a marker armour stand with you and then wait for you to respawn, then teleport, … It's going to get pretty complicated. How about instead clearing the inventory of everyone who died and respawned except you?

Comment: I want the items of other players to still drop

Comment: Could I make the item get destroyed when I die at create a new one when I respawn

Comment: This could work by using `/loot` with the target `spawn` and the source `kill`: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/loot

Comment: replaceitem entity CrimsonCreates weapon.offhand carrot_on_a_stick{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Dash Attack\"}]"},Enchantments:[{id:"binding_curse",lvl:1},{id:"vanishing_curse",lvl:1}]} 1

Comment: I found this and I think it works

Comment: I realize that the offhand is not very functional, but I could place it in another inventory slot.

Comment: Wait, I see the problem, you can create infinite copies of the item

Comment: I'll have to add a death scoreboard so that I cannot do that

Comment: Kill every carrot on a stick item on ground and give to those who don't have. If they drop, it will disapear and they will get another one